# Program for dot product of 2 vectors in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

Below code has no errors but it is not running.
Help me finding the bug.
What can be done to run the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
    int i, n;
    int vect_A[n], vect_B[n];
    int result = 0;
    
    printf("Put down the size of vectors below\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Write vector A:\t");
    scanf("%d", &vect_A[i-1]);

    printf("Write vector B:\t");
    scanf("%d", &vect_B[i-1]);

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result += vect_A[i]*vect_B[i];
    }
    printf("The inner product of these two vectors is %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: "Below code has no errors" -- hm. When you define `int vect_A[n]`, what's the value of `n`? When you say `scanf("%d", &vect_A[i-1])`, what's the value of `i`? How many values do you scan for each vector?

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/zsvzjo

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n)` doesn't work backwards. C isn't a declarative language. It operates according to the flow of statements.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `int i, n` declared, both of the variables are not initialized. C/C++ does not initialize most variables to a value automatically. Therefore when a variable is assigned a memory location by the compiler, the "initialized" value of that variable is whatever happens to be in that memory location before. It's a garbage value. After you update the size of the vectors, that doesn't carry over to your array size that you declared. You can check this by using the sizeof() (ie. `sizeof(vect_A) / sizeof(vect_A[0])` to get the number of elements in the array).

Another thing is that you are only filling in one element into the vectors. You can use a for loop to add terms in the array after the user inputs a value for n.

This worked for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
    int i, n;
    int result = 0;

    printf("Put down the size of vectors below\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int vect_A[n], vect_B[n];

    printf("Write vector A:\t");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      printf("Term %d = ", i);
      scanf("%d", &vect_A[i]);
    }

    printf("Write vector B:\t");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      printf("Term %d = ", i);
      scanf("%d", &vect_B[i]);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result += vect_A[i]*vect_B[i];
    }
        printf("The inner product of these two vectors is %d\n", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`n` is undefined when you declare the vectors. Also `i` is undefined when the user is asked to input the vectors. I guess you meant to have it like this:

```
int main(){

  int i, n;
  printf("Put down the size of vectors below\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  
  int vect_A[n], vect_B[n];
  int result = 0;
    
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf("Write vector A:\t");
      scanf("%d", &vect_A[i]);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf("Write vector B:\t");
      scanf("%d", &vect_B[i]);
    }
    
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result += vect_A[i]*vect_B[i];
    }
    printf("The inner product of these two vectors is %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Not _undefined_ but  _uninitialized_